# How can i use intake library to create one catalog.yaml file to reference nested directories?

Tags: python, catalog

I have the following nested directories:

```
\---population
    +---asia
    |   |   asia_pop.csv
    |   |   
    |   +---china
    |   |       china_pop.csv
    |   |       
    |   \---japan
    |           japan_pop.csv
    |           
    \---europe
        |   europe_total_pop.csv
        |   
        +---france
        |       france_pop.csv
        |       
        \---uk
                uk_pop.csv
```

Is there anyway to create one catalog.yaml file that can work it way through the directories in the following manner?

```
Import intake
root = intake.open_catalog(‘/population/population.yaml’)

# load china population

root.asia.china.read()
```

I know it is possible by nesting multiple catalog.yaml file but is there any way of doing it in one file.

For example:

```
metadata:
  version:1

sources:
  asia:
    china:
      driver: csv
      args:
        skiprows:10
        url:'/population/asia/china/china_pop.csv'
      metadata: {}

    japan:
      driver: csv
      args:
        skiprows:10
        url:'/population/asia/japan/japan_pop.csv'
      metadata: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `intake`, but you can do it directly like this:

```py
import yaml

catalog = yaml.load('/population/population.yaml')

pop_file = open(catalog.sources.asia.china.args.url, "r")
pop_file.read()
```

Comment: thanks for replaying, but intake has the properties that allow you to pass additional argument to the driver when loading the dataset ie skip 10 row. this mean once i load the file using intake catalog i do not need to do any further manipulation. not sure if this possible to do using yaml.load() ?